# to record audio and then to playback with AudioRecord, AudioTrack.trouble

Tags: android, audio-recording, audiorecord, audiotrack, android-audiorecord

i made a audio-recording in real-time and then playback, but when i get started
it sounded very noisy sounds and my voice. so i want to get my voice only with clean tone

im implementing this app with reverb, bass boost, equalizer and visualizer effects

i just wanna clean sounds without those effects

as for this app target version is at least for Android 2.3.3(api 10)

**Q : how do i have to modify this substantial code part? (for audioRecord.startRecording, audioTrack.record, audioTrack.write)**

here is my code snippet as below :

////////////////////////////////////

```
private void main() {

        for (;;) {

            Log.d("AFX", "Starting audio thread");
            this.audioRecord.startRecording();
            this.audioTrack.play();

            int i;

            if (!this.running) {
                this.audioRecord.stop();
                this.audioTrack.stop();
                this.audioRecord.release();
                return;
            }

            i = this.audioRecord.read(this.buffer, 0, this.chunkSize);
            Log.v("AudioRecord", "read " + this.chunkSize + "bytes");

            try {

                // Log.d("AFX", "Starting audio thread");
                this.audioRecord.startRecording();
                this.audioTrack.play();
                Log.d("AFX", "Starting audio thread");

                boolean flag = this.running; // df value : false

                if (!flag) {
                    this.audioRecord.stop();
                    this.audioTrack.stop();
                    // this.audioRecord.release(); // added
                    // this.audioTrack.release(); // added
                    Log.d("AFX", "Exiting audio thread");
                    return;
                }

                i = this.audioRecord.read(this.buffer, 0, this.chunkSize);
                Log.v("AudioRecord", "read " + this.chunkSize + "bytes");

                if (i < 0) {
                    Log.e("AFX", "Record error: " + i);
                    this.running = false;
                    continue;
                    // break;
                }
                if (!this.running) {
                    continue;
                    // break;
                }

            } finally {
                this.audioRecord.stop();
                // this.audioRecord.release(); // added
                this.audioTrack.stop();
                // this.audioTrack.release(); // added
            }

            this.audioTrack.write(this.buffer, 0, i);
            // Log.d("AFX", "Starting audio thread");
            // this.audioRecord.startRecording();
            // this.audioTrack.play();
        }
    }
```

any idea'll be appreciated

thank you much

Answer (score 3):

Try [AudioEffects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html).

```
ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION, SAMPLE_RATE_IN_HZ, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bs * 10);

        if(AutomaticGainControl.isAvailable())
        {
            AutomaticGainControl agc =AutomaticGainControl.create(ar.getAudioSessionId());
            //agc.g
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "AGC is " + (agc.getEnabled()?"enabled":"disabled"));
            agc.setEnabled(true);
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "AGC is " + (agc.getEnabled()?"enabled":"disabled" +" after trying to enable"));
        }else
        {
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "AGC is unavailable");
        }

        if(NoiseSuppressor.isAvailable()){
            NoiseSuppressor ns = NoiseSuppressor.create(ar.getAudioSessionId());
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "NS is " + (ns.getEnabled()?"enabled":"disabled"));
            ns.setEnabled(true);
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "NS is " + (ns.getEnabled()?"enabled":"disabled" +" after trying to disable"));
        }else
        {
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "NS is unavailable");
        }
        if(AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable()){

            AcousticEchoCanceler aec = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(ar.getAudioSessionId());
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "AEC is " + (aec.getEnabled()?"enabled":"disabled"));
            aec.setEnabled(true);
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "AEC is " + (aec.getEnabled()?"enabled":"disabled" +" after trying to disable"));

        }else
        {
            Log.d("AudioRecord", "aec is unavailable");
        }
```

They work on api 16+, but they have also Equalizer, Bass boost and other stuff you mention. Setup them before starting recording.

Comment: my app is targetting for at least android 2.3.3(API 10). @Raiv

Answer (score 0):

In your question you are a bit unspecific about the type of noise you are experiencing.
But if you record and play back the same sound, you are likely to experience severe feedback or echos. Usually a very loud high pitch sound.

Android has built in echo cancellation to solve this problem. It is enabled by default if you use AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, like this:

```
recorder = new AudioRecord( AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, 
                            44100,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                            n );
```

Also, 44100 is the only sample rate that is guaranteed to work on all Android devices. Don't use anything else, or you may get strange results.

Comment: this noise is very unstable, to check it, i want that you directly play my app, if possible. hmm @TimmyBrolin

Comment: VOICE_COMMUNICATION is available since API level 11.

You could possibly use VOICE_CALL as fallback. It should typically have echo cancellation, but is not guaranteed to have it. It is available since API level 4.

VOICE_COMMUNICATION is better defined, so it behaves in a more uniform manner across devices.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_COMMUNICATION

Comment: the target version of this app is for at least api 10+(android 2.3.3 over).. 
:(, but i feel thankful of your idea!

Comment: If the noise is unstable, lound and is echoing your voice, then you are experiencing feedback.
Just try "VOICE_COMMUNICATION" and see what happens. If it solves the problem, then you will just have to figure out a workaround for API 10.

Comment: A hardware solution to feedback problems is to hook up an external microphone or speaker to the phone, and place the speaker and microphone far apart. A headset also works.
Perhaps this can be an acceptable workaround for users on Android 2.3?

Comment: i think this trouble is not for the feedback problems, it entirely counts on my code now. my prototype app has not trouble like this before. somehow thank you

Comment: Remember to vote up (upwards arrow) answers that were useful to you. Use the green checkmark (accepted answer) if a answer solved your problem.

Comment: i solved this problem, it was entirely problems for the source code. i edited it and it's going well, but thank you for your answer